# How the Number function interacts with the operator new

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In this case, the built-in function `Number` was found. I would like to consider it, because the questions I ask below are found in other functions in the specification.

If we open the specification, we see the following:

> **20.1.1.1 Number ( value )**
>
> When Number is called with argument value, the following steps are
>   taken:
>
> 1. If no arguments were passed to this function invocation, let n be
>      +0.
> 2. Else, let n be ? ToNumber(value).
> 3. If NewTarget is undefined, return n.
> 4. Let O be ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget,
>      "%NumberPrototype%", « [[NumberData]] »).
> 5. Set O.[[NumberData]] to n.
> 6. Return O.

Based on this, I want to ask a few questions:

1. `NewTarget` where does it come from?
2. If this algorithm is used both for the constructor and for a simple conversion to a number, then if `NewTarget = undefined` this conversion to a number, if `NewTarget != undefined`, then this calls this function as a constructor.

---

Let's go further to clarify all the points.

> **12.3.3.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation**
>
> NewExpression:new NewExpression
>
> 1. Return ? EvaluateNew(NewExpression, empty).
>
> MemberExpression:new MemberExpressionArguments
>
> 1. Return ? EvaluateNew(MemberExpression, Arguments).
>
> **12.3.3.1.1 Runtime Semantics: EvaluateNew ( constructExpr, arguments )**
>
> The abstract operation EvaluateNew with arguments constructExpr, and
>   arguments performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Assert: constructExpr is either a NewExpression or a
>      MemberExpression.
> 2. Assert: arguments is either empty or an Arguments.
> 3. Let ref be the result of evaluating constructExpr.
> 4. Let constructor be ? GetValue(ref).
> 5. If arguments is empty, let argList be a new empty List.
> 6. Else,
>      a. Let argList be ArgumentListEvaluation of arguments.
>
>    b. ReturnIfAbrupt(argList).
> 7. If IsConstructor(constructor) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
> 8. Return ? Construct(constructor, argList).

When you call a function via the `new` operator (we will act without arguments so easily), we'll see that we have the `Return 'line. EvaluateNew (NewExpression, empty)` In this line, `NewExpression` is the `Number` function, right? If everything is correct go further. Next, we see that in the `EvaluateNew` algorithm there is a line that looks like this: `Let's get the result of evaluating constructExpr.` - what does this mean? This means that we need to calculate what is `ref` before continuing to execute the algorithm? If I'm not mistaken, then `ref` is a `Number` function. So we are asked to execute the lines of the algorithm from the `Number` function? If this is the case, then we are faced with a problem in the `Number` algorithm because we do not know what value `NewTarget` has.

That you understood a question consists in that that I do not understand as the `Number` interacts with the `operator new`. I ask to help you figure it out.

P.S For voters down: explain what you do not like so that I can change the question for the better, thanks

Comment: Your second question is not a question.

Comment: @Bergi Mmm, yes it turned out, but in general it was a question because I wanted to understand if it's right that I wrote or not. You wrote that this is a correct statement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `NewTarget` - where does it come from?

From either [[[call]]ing a builtin function object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) or from [[[construct]]ing a builtin function object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget).

> If this algorithm is used both for the constructor and for a simple conversion to a number, then if `NewTarget = undefined` this conversion to a number, if `NewTarget != undefined`, then this calls this function as a constructor.

That's not a question, that's a (true) statement.

> In this line, `NewExpression` is the `Number` function, right?

No. The NewExpression `constructExpr` is an *expression*, i.e. the abstract syntax tree of whatever operand the `new` operator has. This could be any expression, for example a PrimaryExpression with an IdentifierReference, that evaluates to the global `Number` function (or a Reference to it) - when it is being evaluated, and that's exactly what step 3 does.

Comment: If I understood correctly, `NewExpression` is an abstract expression with which no action is taken, until a certain time. The third step tells us to evaluate. This means that we need to find out what kind of data we have passed (I mean the pass through the syntax tree to the `terminals`). Yes, as I understand the result is the type of `reference`. And yes you probably meant `IdentifierReference`, because I did not find the `IdentifierExpression`. Right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction. And yes, in `new Number` the expression results in a Reference, but e.g. in `new (1, Number)` it doesn't and will evaluate to a value right away.

Comment: And what will be the result of the evaluation `new (1, Number)`? Not a `Reference`? http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-comma-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation and http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-grouping-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation So result of evaluating `Reference`. Is not it?

Comment: @MaximPro The comma operator calls `GetValue` already. After that you got just a function object value, not a Reference. Hint: it's a Reference only when you can assign to it or `delete` it.

Comment: Well you are right in comma operator, we really do `GetValue`, but before it we do: `Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression`. So we still get `Reference`.  One thing is not clear if we get `Reference` in comma operator, and then through `GetValue (Reference)` we get the function object. How will the actions in `EvaluateNew` be performed? What happens with steps 3 and 4?

Comment: @MaximPro I don't care what `rref` in the comma operation evaluation is, I said that the `(1, Number)` member expression evaluates to the function object (in step 3 of EvaluateNew). In step 4, it does nothing since we have a value already - see step 1 of GetValue.

Comment: Do you say about `ReturnIfAbrupt(V)` or `If Type(V) is not Reference, return V`? It's about GetValue steps.

Comment: @MaximPro Oops you're right, I mean step 2 of course. I hadn't bothered to look in the spec…